# Override longpress Home Button Action (Assistant)

Tags: android

It is possible to long press on the home button in Android 6 and the scan the screen (Now on tap, or the [Assist API](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#assist)), which uses an accessibility feature to scan the screen.

[image: Example of the Assist Api]

Is it possible to override the long press behavior. If yes which intent filter is it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to override the long press behavior.

You can create your own assistant. The user can then opt into using your assistant, instead of Now On Tap, via the Settings app.

Otherwise, you have no means of intercepting a long-press on navigation buttons like HOME.

> If yes which intent filter is it?

Um, it's significantly more complicated than that, and there's no activity required in the process. The limited documentation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant.html#implementing_your_own_assistant), and [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Assist/AssistLogger) of mine implements one.

Answer (score 2):

The intent action for the "intent-filter" is

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST"/>
```

You might read 
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant.html